# Dynamic dependent select menus

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a dynamic dependent menu using a jquery script i found on the web.
And then i styled the menus using the well known jquery.uniform script.
You can see how that looks like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bs5Db/50/.

The only disfunction of that code is that once you select a county from one state and then you switch to another state,the name of the last county selected remains appended in the select menu.

I hope someone with some jquery experience takes a look at the code and gives some advice of how to make the counties select menu have the right value everytime the first one is changed.

I exxperimented a liitle myself but with no luck!
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update the uniform plugin.

```
$.uniform.update();
```

So within drop_down_list() function right before you show it.
So insert after this:

```
$('#loading_county_drop_down').hide(); // Hide the Loading...
```

Here is the jsfiddle updated. Your only problem is that the options are too long and goto second line.

http://jsfiddle.net/jJa67/